# How would I modify an outside variable within a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, variable-assignment

Python code:

```py
i: int = 1
table: list = [[i, bit, None, None] for bit in h]
```

Expected behaviour: `i` needs to be incremented by 1 per iteration.

Pseudocode:

```py
i: int = 1
table: list = [[i++, bit, None, None] for bit in h]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

List comprehensions shouldn't be used for outside side-effects.  In this case, use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead of an outside variable:

```py
h = '10010010'  # Undefined in OP example.  Just something to enumerate.
table = [[i, bit, None, None ] for i, bit in enumerate(h, start=1)]
for row in table:
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
[1, '1', None, None]
[2, '0', None, None]
[3, '0', None, None]
[4, '1', None, None]
[5, '0', None, None]
[6, '0', None, None]
[7, '1', None, None]
[8, '0', None, None]
```

Answer (score 4):

As a thought experiment that's the literal answer to your question:

```py
>>> i=0
>>> [[i:=i+1, bit, None, None] for bit in h]
[[1, '1', None, None], [2, '0', None, None], [3, '0', None, None], [4, '1', None, None], [5, '0', None, None], [6, '0', None, None], [7, '1', None, None], [8, '0', None, None]]
```

you definitely shouldn't be doing that, and go with `enumerate` instead per accepted answer

Comment: this is the most [cursed special case](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/#scope-of-the-target) in the language, IMO it should have never been allowed in PEP 572

Answer (score 0):

More ways to get the result:

```
[[i, bit, None, None]
 for i in [0]
 for bit in h
 for i in [i+1]]

[a[:]
 for a in [[None] * 4]
 for a[:2] in enumerate(h, start=1)]

[[*tpl]
 for nones in [repeat(None)]
 for tpl in zip(count(1), h, nones, nones)]

[*map(list, zip(count(1), h, nones := repeat(None), nones))]
```

Benchmark, can't currently run it :-(

```py
import timeit

setup = '''
from itertools import count, repeat
h = '10010010'
'''

codes = [
    'lst = [[i, bit, None, None ] for i, bit in enumerate(h, start=1)]',
    'i=0; lst = [[i:=i+1, bit, None, None] for bit in h]',
    'lst = [[i, bit, None, None] for i in [0] for bit in h for i in [i+1]]',
    'lst = [a[:] for a in [[None] * 4] for a[:2] in enumerate(h, start=1)]',
    'lst = [[*tpl] for nones in [repeat(None)] for tpl in zip(count(1), h, nones, nones)]',
    'lst = [*map(list, zip(count(1), h, nones := repeat(None), nones))]',
]

exec(setup)
for code in codes:
    exec(code)
    print(lst)
    del lst

setup = '''
from itertools import count, repeat
h = '10010010' * 1000
'''

for code in codes:
    t = min(timeit.repeat(code, setup, number=10, repeat=25)) / 10
    print(f'{t * 1e3:4.2f} ms ', code)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=pVNLTsMwEF2w8ylm57iEkpRWQkG5AheIskhbR7EUx5Y9kfiIk7DpBg7FafAnQYVSsSCK4oznzXsznvHru37ETg2Hw9uI7dXtx8VGSK0MAgrJBRJiOY4aSqCUktYoCQK5QaV6CxNyp8YBUzBc8wZJ57F5loWXEh9GdmrPrduvCLiH9ha9UYkUtsJF3quBxy_U0CoD0QFiAD6MkpsGedKlYLExWOaspmkkEmV2B19sRSku8xPKyDjRdV-h53OYUvDwKvsefeRxUvVPsqYqIr4JkCqyLWA97VbFqv67qDmzBeo-Bg6OxwbKeMaJJ2bR50De8yR0EvqQ5CwFRxtipuWEeyEbnfTCurp_D4SihGOtmSgw1YTwB75LwmQw4rPwDfZphEYXQStAvM2CqY1wGk4_mnve-8b9d7zc4bqfLE7ZmUR8xVIMSRzo5VSWB7jD9-quuFFuuSnzbJYpVxvG4NqRHyXf0mf0gvymWC9X7QtICzQNUizenukSzZfpEw)